# Java compile error

Tags: java, compilation, boolean

Could you help me to explain what this error message means when I tried to compile Java code?

```
Matching.java:128: error: ';' expected
    If (nIsBigger==true){
                        ^
```

I don't think `;` is needed after the `if ()` ?

Comment: Did you really spell `If` with a capital `i`?

Comment: if should be with lowercase i: if(nIsBigger){

Comment: For booleans you don't need `==true` anyway, just `if(nIsBigger) { ...` will do.

Comment: All keywords in Java are purely in lower case.  i.e. case matters in Java.

Answer (score 7):

This is wrong

```
If (nIsBigger==true){ // capital I
```

It should be

```
if (nIsBigger==true){
```

And again, explicit comparison to true is redundant, just write:

```
if (nIsBigger){} // since nIsBigger is already a boolean value
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong Way to wite `If`

```
 If (nIsBigger==true){
```

write Like:`if`

```
          if(nIsBigger==true)
           {
           }
```